# How do I force a div to hold its aspect ratio in a flex object?

Tags: html, css, rounding, responsive, aspect-ratio

I am trying to make a responsive description window that contains a round picture. (A square `div` with `aspect-ratio:1/1` and `border-radius:50%`) However, while it remains a perfect circle when the window is being resized vertically, horizontal resizing results in the image squishing. I have tried fiddling with the CSS code, tried various suggestions - applying padding, applying `margin:auto`, reading other stackoverflow answers but nothing worked for me. Can anyone with more experience in this help me? Excuse my spaghetti code, I just copy-pasted it from my project, I didn't change anything. Here it is:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/brch_/pen/JjLwjeK)

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
}

.popcontent {
  transition: 1s;
  filter: opacity(1);
  display: flex;
  z-index: 5;
  position: fixed;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 10vh 0 0 5vw;
  width: 90%;
  height: 80%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

.exit {
  position: absolute;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  width: 4%;
  right: 0;
}

.exit div:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
}

.exit div:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}

.exit div {
  height: 5px;
  width: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform-origin: center;
  background-color: #222d3e;
}

.popcontent #a {
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.popcontent #b {
  flex: 2;
  overflow: scroll;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  text-align: justify;
}

.popcontent #b p {
  margin: auto;
}

.popcontent #a,
.popcontent #b {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  padding: 3%;
}

.roundin {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.roundin div {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.roundimage {
  aspect-ratio: 1/1 !important;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #222D3E;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="popcontent">
  <div class="exit">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div id="a">
    <div class="roundin">
      <div class="roundimage" style="background-image:url('/link/to/image')"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <p>Name</p>
      <p>+12345678901</p>

      <a href="#">http://www.example.com</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="b">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the **One Word FIX**;

- Just make your `.roundin` class `display: block`

[image: here is the fix]

Comment: Thank you! But now another problem appears - the whole `#a` part overflows if squished vertically...